# Using a Joker with two tiles from my rack and one from the board

Tags: rummikub

I don't quite know the lingo, so apologies for that:

The Joker was on the board in place of a black 2 - I replaced it with a black 2, and I know that I have to use it with 2 tiles from my hand to make a meld. I have a red 5 and a red 8. There is a red 7 elsewhere on the board. So I did red 5-J-7-8.

Technically, two of those tiles came from my hand. However, I was *only* able to make the meld with the red 7 on the table. My mom said it was against the rules, that you needed to be able to use the two tiles in your hand with the Joker to make a complete set.

My red 5 and red 8 alone couldn't make a complete set with the joker...but technically I *did* use the Joker in a new set with 2 tiles from my rack. So which of us is right?

Comment: Can you please quote the exact wording of your rules? You say "*I have to use it with 2 tiles from my hand*", [Gregor](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7160/11743) thinks his rules say "*you must immediately replay the joker in a run or set with at least 2 tiles from your hand*". Without an exact quote from the rules (and there are a few different versions out there) it's almost impossible to know which interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

My rules state:

> The tile used to replace a joker must come from a player's rack and not from the table. A joker that has been replaced must be used in the player's same turn with 2 or more tiles from his rack to make a new set.

So, playing with my set of the rules, no, the example above would not be legal. The new set would need to stand alone. Adding that '7' midstream would not be part of the 'two or more tiles from his rack to make a new set.'

Comment: Hi Gary. As per my comments everywhere else on this question: there is more than one rule set in existence. I've edited your answer to make it clear that it only applies when using the particular rule set that you have. That said, your rules are probably at least similar to the OP's, seeing as you have the rule about two tiles from the hand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved still further with a reference, i.e. either a link to an online version of your rule set, or a citation saying who published your version of the rules and when (probably in small text at the bottom of a paper set of the rules).

Comment: Oh, and welcome to boardgames.SE! :)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no rule which says you may only use the joker in combination with tiles from your hand.

Tiles reused from the table must remain at the table (you can't take remaining tiles on your rack). This also applies to jokers.
So what you did is correct.

To stress it even more: if the table has 2-3-4 and you have 6, you can use the joker to build 2-3-4-j-6 so you only used 1 card of your rack.

Comment: The OP has a different ruleset to what you are clearly used to. The only way an answer is going to be useful to the OP is if it's related to the ruleset they have.

Answer (score -2):

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/7195/25029 seems to put a definitive end to this question. The rule is that when replacing the joker, one must use it to make a set on that turn. Apparently large rules changes have ocurred within the game.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP is presumably using a different set of rules to the latest version.