# Rules when using a Joker

Tags: rummikub, joker

I had on my rack among other tiles, a black 9, 1 x blue 10, and a black 12.

On the table was a set of 3 x 10s including a Joker(no blue 10), and other sets of tiles including an available black 11.

Can I replace the joker with my blue 10 and then set out :

my black 9, the joker(representing a black 10), a black 11 from the table, and my black 12?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44373/rummikub-using-a-joker-with-two-tiles-from-my-rack-and-one-from-the-board. But can't be marked as a duplicate because that one has no upvoted answer...

Comment: @AndyT that's not a duplicate -- that one asks about needing to use an additional tile from the board (in addition to two from your hand, which that OP's rules required).

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson - Yes, and no. If David Young has the rule that "you must use two tiles from your hand" then it's identical. There's no indication from David Young as to what wording his ruleset has... so who knows whether it's a duplicate or not?

Comment: @AndyT, even if he using the same ruleset, this is a different question / more expansive question. This question is about what tile can be used to take the Joker from the set of three; a point the linked question doesn't have.

Answer (score 4):

Note: all quotes taken from [this set of rules](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/rummikub.html).

Yes, you can replace the Joker with either of the missing 10s (in this case, a blue 10)

> In the case of group consisting of two equal tiles and a joker, the joker can be replaced by a matching tile of either of the missing colors.

Yes, you can use the retrieved joker as any tile; you are free to change the color and/or rank it represents.

> a player who has in hand the tile which is represented by a joker on the table, the player can substitute the real tile for the joker and then re-use the joker in some combination on the table.

And note: this is "yes" only if you've already set out your initial meld. You can't retrieve a joker before putting down your first meld.

> The first meld made by each player must consist of one or more combinations formed entirely from that player's hand

Comment: Well done for saying which version of rules, but it's worth noting that joker rules vary significantly across different versions; so the OP's edition of the rules may not agree with your answer.

Comment: True, Rummikub is a venerable game. (If you find rules that are at odds with my answer, let me know and I'll include them)

Comment: Here's a good summary of all the (possible) rules: [boardgamegeek.com](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/371138/old-rules-new-rules). Personally I grew up with the same rules that Gregor had on [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7160/do-you-have-to-play-a-replaced-joker-immediately-with-2-tiles-from-your-hand).